# Calculate average vector of a text on SpaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm using SpaCy calculate de distance between several documents, my approach is the as follows:

1) Convert the text into a spacy object
2) Remove the stop words
3) For each of the remaining words, get the vector representation and calculate the average. 
4) Use several methods to measure the distance between the documents.

My problem with this approach is that it takes a long time for big documents.

I have found the spacy has a method, called similarity, to do this that works faster:

```
nlp_latin = spacy.load("/tmp/la_vectors_wiki_lg")
doc1 = nlp_latin(u"Caecilius est in horto")
doc2 = nlp_latin(u"servus est in atrio")
doc1.similarity(doc2)
```

But it uses cosine distance only, is there a method that just return the average vector of the document?

Comment: Per the docs "Models that come with built-in word vectors make them available as the `Token.vector` attribute. `Doc.vector` and `Span.vector` will default to an average of their token vectors."

Comment: @bivouac0 please answer that to close the question (y)

Answer (score 3):

Just expanding upon the answer in the comments above for future visitors of this thread:

According to the [SpaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/api/doc#vector), the `Doc` class in SpaCy has a property `vector` that returns the average of its token vectors.

For your use-case, after loading SpaCy, the following code will give you the average vector for the Latin text "Caecilius est in horto"

```
doc = nlp_latin(u"Caecilius est in horto")
doc.vector
```

**Sidenotes to increase performance:**

1. Even though you are only using the tokenizer component of the SpaCy pipeline, SpaCy loads other components (namely, "parser", "ner", "tagger" and "textcat") when you call `spacy.load`. Therefore, loading them significantly reduces performance. To solve this, you can exclude these additional components by adding the `exclude` parameter to the `spacy.load` function, as shown below (For more information, check out the [Spacy documentation on processing pipelines.](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines)):

```
   nlp_latin = spacy.load("/tmp/la_vectors_wiki_lg", exclude=["parser", "ner", "tagger", "textcat"])
```

2. Again, since you are only using SpaCy to convert raw text to tokens, you can replace `nlp_latin` function call with `nlp_latin.make_doc`. The average token vector can be retrieved with `doc.vector` as before. This ensures that SpaCy is only using the tokenizer after the nlp_latin call, making your code even faster. For more information, check out the [Scaling and Performance section of this link](https://course.spacy.io/en/chapter3)